# jQuery Mobile dialog history

Tags: jquery-mobile

On closing a dialog the default action is to navigate back to the page where the dialog was opened.

We have a use case where this default action is required if the use closes the dialog on clicking a close button.

However, we need the same dialog not to navigate back when the user scans a NFC tag while the dialog is open. We close the dialog programmatically on NFC scan with

```js
$('#interlink').dialog('close');
```

In both cases the dialog needs to be removed from the DOM like

```js
$('#interlink').on('pagehide', function () {
    $(this).remove();
    // remove this views popup-containers 
    $('#interlink-video-popup-popup').remove();
    console.log('removed interlink dialog');
});
```

Is there a way to prevent the default action ( navigating back ) conditionally?

Comment: Use `$.mobile.changePage()` to navigate to a different page. By default it will navigate to the previous page.

Comment: @Omar: You mean instead of closing the dialog? If so, will pagehide still be triggered on the dialog?

Comment: `pagehide` will trigger once dialog is closed. So once dialog is closed, you can move to another page using `$.mobile.changePage('#pageid'`.)

Comment: @Omar: In the NFC event handler we are using $.mobile.navigate(..) to move to another page, however, what's happen is we see the new page for a short moment but then going back to the page where the dialog was triggered.

Comment: Try `$.mobile.changePage`.

Comment: @Omar: no, does not make any difference. Have a lock at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771983/jquery-mobile-dialogs-without-changing-hash) first post under update. However, this is 1.5 years ago and I don't know whether this still applies.

Comment: looks like a no go, and dialog widget will be deprecated in v1.4